# Understanding the backtrace error in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I get the following error when I execute a fortran code compiled with `gfortran`. The error is followed by a backtrace for this error pointing to memory locations.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x2b2f8e39da2d in ???
#1  0x2b2f8e39cc63 in ???
#2  0x311823256f in ???
#3  0x311827a7be in ???
#4  0x2b2f8e39cff2 in ???
#5  0x2b2f8e4adde6 in ???
#6  0x2b2f8e4ae047 in ???
#7  0x2b2f8e4a62d7 in ???
#8  0x40482a in instrument_
    at /home/user/model/instrument.f:90
#9  0x406c1e in funcdet
    at /home/user/model/funcsynth.f:67
#10  0x406c98 in main
    at /home/user/model/funcsynth.f:78
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I would like to know where the first instance of error arises - is it the first line of the backtrace or the lastline? Also, strategies that might help me debug the issue.

**Update:**

Upon backtracing, the line 90 of `instrument` involves opening a file like so:

```
  out_file3 = 'new_file'
  OPEN(unit=3,file=out_file3,status='unknown')
```

To determine the issue behind I've incorporated error checking by doing so:

```
  OPEN(unit=3,file=out_file3,status='unknown',iostat=io_status, err=100)
  100  write(STDOUT,*) 'io status=', io_status
```

The code exits with the error:
Error: Invalid value for ERR specification at (1). How do I determine the appropriate value for ERR specification? This led me to suspect that unit=3 might be the cause for error, I've changed the value for unit, but everytime get the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

**Update 2:**

```
OPEN(unit=3,file=out_file3,status='unknown',err=17)
17  write(STDOUT,*) 'Problem'
```

Still get the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error at the line corresponding to `OPEN...`. I can only guess that `unit=3` is the root cause of the problem.

**Update 3**

Attempt at a self sufficient example:

```
  character*280       testfile,finalfile,outfile
  DIR = '/storage/work/user/'
  testfile = 'test.dat'
  CALL getenv(DIR,outfile)
  CALL sappend(outfile,testfile,finalfile)
  OPEN(unit=3,file=finalfine,status='new')
  write(3,*) 'Test'
  END
```

Comment: The backtrace is an upside-down walk through the (conceptual) call stack of the program, with `main` at the bottom.  It's kind of difficult to investigate what's going on in locations `???`, so you might start your investigations at `/home/user/model/instrument.f:90`.  And if that leads nowhere you might want to fire up a debugger.

Comment: If you haven't already read the documentation, add the `-g` option to the command.  This may help translate the hexadecimal addresses to function names.  You may also want to add `-fcheck=all` to the options.  My guess is that you are indexing an array out-of-bounds in instrument.f.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark how do I run a debugger?

Comment: That's a whole other question and not one I would answer here on SO.  Ask that question of your favourite search engine.

Comment: I've incorporated error checking. But, there is no obvious culprit. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Drop the `err=100` from the `open` statement, and check the value of `io_status`.  Don't use both the old way (`err=`) and the new way (`iostat=`) in the same statement.

Comment: What version of gfortran and what is the exact command line you are using?

Comment: @steve I'm using: GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5). Bash command line.

Comment: Not bash.  The command line would be for example `gfortran -o z file.f90`.  Are you using any unusual command line options?

Comment: OPTIONS=-g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=underflow. These are the options that I'm using.

Comment: We really do need the value of `io_status`. I have asked several times at the duplicate already. It really is necessary. Or tell us that it is not printed, that is also an important information.

Comment: Ignore the `io_status` as it was unnecessarily put in (taking cue from another SO post without realizing that it is a variable). Please see the updated post.

Comment: You've reached the point that a complete self-contained program needs to shown.  Two lines of code isn't enough information, and in fact you may fixated on the wrong lines.

Comment: @steve Updated my attempt in the post

Comment: This line `OPEN(unit=3,file=finalfine,status='new')` isn't going to work very well.   The most recent code isn't really *self sufficient*, it contains calls to two non-standard routines.  `getenv` I'm familiar with and can figure out, `sappend` not so much.  And it omits the most important statement in any modern Fortran program - `implicit none`.  In this case it would have caught the error in the `open` statement, in other cases it will save your bacon time and time again.